# Is there any sort of proposal to improve asynchronous mapping (and other iteration) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that one can do:

```
const results = Promise.all(
  someArray.map(async someThing => 
    await foo(someThing)
  )
);
```

But is there any sort of proposal or anything to improve that to say:

```
const results = someArray.asyncMap(async someThing => 
  await foo(someThing))
```

Similarly with other iteration methods like `find`, `filter`, `some`, etc., there *are* ways to use them asynchronously, but they're far more awkward than their non-asynchronous equivalents.

I'm sure the best minds in Javascript don't want everyone to have to use regular old `for` loops to do all asynchronous work, but since `async`/`await` makes using anything else more awkward, it begs the question ... is anyone trying to improve matters at the language level?

Comment: All proposals can be found here: https://github.com/tc39/proposals (and on the pages the readme links to).

Comment: Thank you for that link, but there's a lot of proposals and a lot of jargon, so I'd appreciate an answer still if possible, as I'm not sure I can find one myself within all that (again, not knowing all the jargon).  Also, proposals must start somewhere before reaching stage 0, and I'd be curious (even if there is nothing stage 0 or higher) if there were any "pre-proposals" ... because again I'm mainly wondering "is anyone working on this"?

Comment: You can simplify to `const results = await Promise.all(someArray.map(foo))`, but no there is no proposal to introduce a `asyncMap` method - it's too trivial to write this helper yourself.

Comment: But again, not *just* map: async makes `find`, `filter`, `some`, `any`, `reduce`, etc. harder also.  Still, if there's truly no proposal to address this, that sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @machineghost `find`, `some` and `any` are not just harder, they're quite complex and would need some kind of cancellation design if you wanted them to run in parallel. (Sequentially, they're all trivial). I don't think there's a lot userland libraries that solve these problems (maybe *async-as-promised*?) where a clear and clean design emerged, so they're unlikely to become part of the standard library soon.